# ftp_put failed to upload large file after some time during uploading

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-upload, ftp

im facing serious issue. i wants to upload zip file of 250MB. when i run php script on my localhost and upload a zip file its successfully uploaded. but when i testing on my web server and run save script it failed to upload after some time. after its failure i go onto ftp account and see it was 55Mb uploaded.
in the same way i once again tested on my web server and try to upload same file, now its again failed and when i check my ftp account directory its 37Mb uploaded. its means ftp_put gets fail during uploading of larger files.

so here is my code.

```
$ftp = new ftp();
$ftp->debug = false;
$ftp->timeout = 1;
if (!$ftp->ftp_connect($ftp_host, $port = 21)) {
  echo 'note connected';
}

if (!$ftp->ftp_login($ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
   echo 'could not login';
}
$ftp->ftp_chdir($directory_path);

$ftp->ftp_put($remote_filename, $local_filename,FTP_BINARY);
```

here is my .htaccess settings

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 300M
php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
php_value memory_limit 600M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200

</IfModule>
```

Note: im sending ajax request error reporting is set to 1 in script file. 
im 100% sure that error is comming from $ftp->ftp_put line during uploading file to ftp server.

Comment: It may be Internet speed problem .Please check it

Comment: no its not internet issue. i uploaded my script on web server.

Comment: Any solution ? Please share ?